# How to get address of a cupy array?

Tags: cupy

Is there a way to get the memory address of cupy arrays? similar to pytorch and numpy tensors/arrays, we can get the address of the first element and compare them:
For pytorch:

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = x[:2]
z = x[2:]
print(x.data_ptr() == y.data_ptr())  # True
print(x.data_ptr() == z.data_ptr())  # False
```

For numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = x[:2]
z = x[2:]
print(x.ctypes.data == y.ctypes.data)  # True
print(x.ctypes.data == z.ctypes.data)  # False
```

Comment: See here. https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/user_guide/interoperability.html#device-memory-pointers